# How to use regex for numbers in the string?

Tags: linux, bash

For example I have files that have names like

- book1_volume1.txt
- book1_volume2.txt
- book1_review.txt
- book2_volume1.txt

How can I find all 'book%NUMBER%_volume' files in one search? How do I mask the number after 'book'?

Comment: The simplest wait to do so is to use _wildcards_, specifically `book[0-9]_volume*` matches

Comment: Man, this was really simple! Thank you. Can you make an answer so I could mark it as the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do so is to use [wildcards](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm), specifically `book[0-9]_volume*` matches your example.

Answer (score 2):

If there can be more than one digit, use an [extended pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
books=( book_+([0-9])_volume* )
```